# I can't seem to populate a Textbox with the Model's property value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to populate the textbox like this:

```
<span class="display-label">Volume Amount:</span><span>@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.VolumeAmount)</span>
```

This does not work. The textbox is displayed but the property's text never populates the field. However If I do it this way:

```
<span class="display-label">Volume Amount:</span><span><input type"text" name="VolumeAmount" value="@(Model.VolumeAmount)" /></span>
```

Everything seems to work great, but when the field is changed I won't be able to update the property without doing some AJAX.

Note: This is inside of a partial view which is loaded from a View. The View which loads it loads the partial view inside of an existing Form element.

Comment: Just tested this on a simple empty MVC3 app and is working fine for me (I copy & pasted you code)...

Comment: just curious...what datatype is VolumeAmount??? if its a decimal or int...can you try changing that to a string and see if it populates...

Comment: VolumeAmount is a decimal? (Thats not a question... its shorthand for Nullable Decimal)

Comment: I changed the VolumeAmount in the model to a string... and it didn't make a difference. I does still work to put it into an <input type="text" ... field though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller try:

```
ModelState.Clear();
```

MVC likes to hang on to states from previous posts.

Answer (score 1):

Write the mvc model variables in aspx pages included in the following using clause

```
<% using(Html.BeginForm("HandleForm", "Home")) %>
<% { %>
    <!-- Form content goes here -->
<% } %>
```

Refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410596.aspx

Comment: Also.. I am using Razor Views so my annotations are done differently.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your text boxes inside of form. Try to check any samples. For example: create asp.net mvc project and open Login (Login.cshtml) view of Account controller. It lets you figure out how it works.

Comment: Yes... I'm sorry I didn't mention that earlier. This is in a partial view. I'll edit my original post and put that information in.